# how to make image transition as below

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello i am curently trying to re create a transition and playing with opacity to switch images on hover but maybe it is due to object-fit cover property the image kinda zooms in when i increase container width on hover and would like to ask your help on this problem i am also posting gif for what i want it to be and whats it is currenlty now:
[image]

you  can view the gif to get the idea what i am trying to make and below is my html and css code i have tried till now:

```css
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Roboto&family=Shantell+Sans:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap');

    * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
       
    }
    :root{

    --small : url("https://i.ibb.co/1MYMcPX/MV5-BY2-Q1-Zj-Bj-MTMt-Nj-Qx-OS00-OTRk-LThm-Zj-Ut-ZWUy-Mz-Vh-MTA4-MGE1-Xk-Ey-Xk-Fqc-Gde-QXVy-NTgx-ODY.jpg");
    --image : url("https://i.ibb.co/TMn41Gs/ezgif-com-gif-maker.jpg");
    }
    body {
        min-height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        
    }
    body::after{
        position:absolute; 
        width:0; 
        height:0; 
        overflow:hidden;
         z-index:-1; 
        content: var(--image)
     }
    .container{
       
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        scrollbar-width: none;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        width: 600px;
    }
    .container::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
      }
    .item{
        display: inline-block;
        height: 160px;
        width: 130px;
      position: relative;
        transition: all 0.5s linear;
    }
    img{
      position: absolute;
        object-fit: cover;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
    }
    img:nth-child(1){
        opacity: 1;
    }
    img:nth-child(2){
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .item:hover{
       width: 300px;
    }
    .item:hover img:nth-child(1){
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .item:hover img:nth-child(2){
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"
            integrity="sha512-pumBsjNRGGqkPzKHndZMaAG+bir374sORyzM3uulLV14lN5LyykqNk8eEeUlUkB3U0M4FApyaHraT65ihJhDpQ=="
            crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        <title>Goggle movies</title>
        <script src="index.js" defer></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="item">
              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/1MYMcPX/MV5-BY2-Q1-Zj-Bj-MTMt-Nj-Qx-OS00-OTRk-LThm-Zj-Ut-ZWUy-Mz-Vh-MTA4-MGE1-Xk-Ey-Xk-Fqc-Gde-QXVy-NTgx-ODY.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/TMn41Gs/ezgif-com-gif-maker.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/1MYMcPX/MV5-BY2-Q1-Zj-Bj-MTMt-Nj-Qx-OS00-OTRk-LThm-Zj-Ut-ZWUy-Mz-Vh-MTA4-MGE1-Xk-Ey-Xk-Fqc-Gde-QXVy-NTgx-ODY.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/TMn41Gs/ezgif-com-gif-maker.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/1MYMcPX/MV5-BY2-Q1-Zj-Bj-MTMt-Nj-Qx-OS00-OTRk-LThm-Zj-Ut-ZWUy-Mz-Vh-MTA4-MGE1-Xk-Ey-Xk-Fqc-Gde-QXVy-NTgx-ODY.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/TMn41Gs/ezgif-com-gif-maker.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/1MYMcPX/MV5-BY2-Q1-Zj-Bj-MTMt-Nj-Qx-OS00-OTRk-LThm-Zj-Ut-ZWUy-Mz-Vh-MTA4-MGE1-Xk-Ey-Xk-Fqc-Gde-QXVy-NTgx-ODY.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/TMn41Gs/ezgif-com-gif-maker.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>


    </html>
```

what i want to know is how to make transition shown on gif i mean my code image zooms in and fits when changing image on hovering

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with the way your snippet is working. Seems fine to me.

Comment: @BrettDonald the images kinda zooms in when i increase container width on hover compared to gif in which the images places perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to fix the width of the second image to avoid the zooming effect, and then hide overflow on your wrapper items. Add a transition style to your images as well, for the opacity.

```
.item {
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
img:nth-child(2) {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Roboto&family=Shantell+Sans:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap');

    * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
       
    }
    :root{

    --small : url("https://i.ibb.co/1MYMcPX/MV5-BY2-Q1-Zj-Bj-MTMt-Nj-Qx-OS00-OTRk-LThm-Zj-Ut-ZWUy-Mz-Vh-MTA4-MGE1-Xk-Ey-Xk-Fqc-Gde-QXVy-NTgx-ODY.jpg");
    --image : url("https://i.ibb.co/TMn41Gs/ezgif-com-gif-maker.jpg");
    }
    body {
        min-height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        
    }
    body::after{
        position:absolute; 
        width:0; 
        height:0; 
        overflow:hidden;
         z-index:-1; 
        content: var(--image)
     }
    .container{
       
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        scrollbar-width: none;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        width: 600px;
    }
    .container::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
      }
    .item{
        display: inline-block;
        height: 160px;
        width: 130px;
      position: relative;
        transition: all 0.5s linear;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    img{
      position: absolute;
        object-fit: cover;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
        transition: all 0.5s linear;
    }
    img:nth-child(1){
        opacity: 1;
    }
    img:nth-child(2){
        opacity: 0;
        width: 300px;
    }
    .item:hover{
       width: 300px;
    }
    .item:hover img:nth-child(1){
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .item:hover img:nth-child(2){
        opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"
            integrity="sha512-pumBsjNRGGqkPzKHndZMaAG+bir374sORyzM3uulLV14lN5LyykqNk8eEeUlUkB3U0M4FApyaHraT65ihJhDpQ=="
            crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        <title>Goggle movies</title>
        <script src="index.js" defer></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="item">
              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/1MYMcPX/MV5-BY2-Q1-Zj-Bj-MTMt-Nj-Qx-OS00-OTRk-LThm-Zj-Ut-ZWUy-Mz-Vh-MTA4-MGE1-Xk-Ey-Xk-Fqc-Gde-QXVy-NTgx-ODY.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/TMn41Gs/ezgif-com-gif-maker.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/1MYMcPX/MV5-BY2-Q1-Zj-Bj-MTMt-Nj-Qx-OS00-OTRk-LThm-Zj-Ut-ZWUy-Mz-Vh-MTA4-MGE1-Xk-Ey-Xk-Fqc-Gde-QXVy-NTgx-ODY.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/TMn41Gs/ezgif-com-gif-maker.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/1MYMcPX/MV5-BY2-Q1-Zj-Bj-MTMt-Nj-Qx-OS00-OTRk-LThm-Zj-Ut-ZWUy-Mz-Vh-MTA4-MGE1-Xk-Ey-Xk-Fqc-Gde-QXVy-NTgx-ODY.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/TMn41Gs/ezgif-com-gif-maker.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/1MYMcPX/MV5-BY2-Q1-Zj-Bj-MTMt-Nj-Qx-OS00-OTRk-LThm-Zj-Ut-ZWUy-Mz-Vh-MTA4-MGE1-Xk-Ey-Xk-Fqc-Gde-QXVy-NTgx-ODY.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/TMn41Gs/ezgif-com-gif-maker.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>


    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change CSS in the `img` from `object-fit: cover;` to `object-fit: fill;` so
the image will fit without zooming.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Roboto&family=Shantell+Sans:ital,wght@1,300&display=swap');

    * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
       
    }
    :root{

    --small : url("https://i.ibb.co/1MYMcPX/MV5-BY2-Q1-Zj-Bj-MTMt-Nj-Qx-OS00-OTRk-LThm-Zj-Ut-ZWUy-Mz-Vh-MTA4-MGE1-Xk-Ey-Xk-Fqc-Gde-QXVy-NTgx-ODY.jpg");
    --image : url("https://i.ibb.co/TMn41Gs/ezgif-com-gif-maker.jpg");
    }
    body {
        min-height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        
    }
    body::after{
        position:absolute; 
        width:0; 
        height:0; 
        overflow:hidden;
         z-index:-1; 
        content: var(--image)
     }
    .container{
       
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        scrollbar-width: none;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        width: 600px;
    }
    .container::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
      }
    .item{
        display: inline-block;
        height: 160px;
        width: 130px;
      position: relative;
        transition: all 0.5s linear;
    }
    img{
      position: absolute;
        object-fit: fill;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
    }
    img:nth-child(1){
        opacity: 1;
    }
    img:nth-child(2){
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .item:hover{
       width: 300px;
    }
    .item:hover img:nth-child(1){
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .item:hover img:nth-child(2){
        opacity: 1;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"
            integrity="sha512-pumBsjNRGGqkPzKHndZMaAG+bir374sORyzM3uulLV14lN5LyykqNk8eEeUlUkB3U0M4FApyaHraT65ihJhDpQ=="
            crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        <title>Goggle movies</title>
        <script src="index.js" defer></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="item">
              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/1MYMcPX/MV5-BY2-Q1-Zj-Bj-MTMt-Nj-Qx-OS00-OTRk-LThm-Zj-Ut-ZWUy-Mz-Vh-MTA4-MGE1-Xk-Ey-Xk-Fqc-Gde-QXVy-NTgx-ODY.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
              <img src="https://i.ibb.co/TMn41Gs/ezgif-com-gif-maker.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/1MYMcPX/MV5-BY2-Q1-Zj-Bj-MTMt-Nj-Qx-OS00-OTRk-LThm-Zj-Ut-ZWUy-Mz-Vh-MTA4-MGE1-Xk-Ey-Xk-Fqc-Gde-QXVy-NTgx-ODY.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/TMn41Gs/ezgif-com-gif-maker.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/1MYMcPX/MV5-BY2-Q1-Zj-Bj-MTMt-Nj-Qx-OS00-OTRk-LThm-Zj-Ut-ZWUy-Mz-Vh-MTA4-MGE1-Xk-Ey-Xk-Fqc-Gde-QXVy-NTgx-ODY.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/TMn41Gs/ezgif-com-gif-maker.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/1MYMcPX/MV5-BY2-Q1-Zj-Bj-MTMt-Nj-Qx-OS00-OTRk-LThm-Zj-Ut-ZWUy-Mz-Vh-MTA4-MGE1-Xk-Ey-Xk-Fqc-Gde-QXVy-NTgx-ODY.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
                <img src="https://i.ibb.co/TMn41Gs/ezgif-com-gif-maker.jpg" alt="" srcset="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>


    </html>
```

Comment: i dont want the stretch behaviour can you take a look at gif